# I/O error: No route to host; nested exception is java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host

Tags: java, android, resttemplate

I am getting the above exception when trying to consume restservice using resttemplate in android. the following is the piece of code.

```
 private class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ShiftPlannerModel[]> {
    @Override
    protected ShiftPlannerModel[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            ResponseEntity<ShiftPlannerModel[]> greeting = restTemplate.getForEntity(URL, ShiftPlannerModel[].class);
            Log.i(greeting.getBody().toString(), "doInBackground: ");
            return greeting.getBody();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("doInBackgrouExcp", e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

NOTE: rest service is up and running in local machine

[image]

The following is the full stack trace:
4-19 00:56:21.260 11743-11794/com.example.admin.myapplication E/doInBackgrouExcp: I/O error: No route to host; nested exception is java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: No route to host; nested exception is java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:491)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:439)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:259)
        at com.example.admin.myapplication.MainActivity$HttpRequestTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:132)
        at com.example.admin.myapplication.MainActivity$HttpRequestTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:126)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
     Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:334)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:586)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:113)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:1455)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:1413)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:1700)
        at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:133)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:466)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:371)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:130)
        at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:72)
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:46)
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:63)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:476)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:439) 
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:259) 
        at com.example.admin.myapplication.MainActivity$HttpRequestTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:132) 
        at com.example.admin.myapplication.MainActivity$HttpRequestTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:126) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762) 
04-19 00:56:21.261 11743-11743/com.example.admin.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-19 00:56:21.261 11743-11743/com.example.admin.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.admin.myapplication, PID: 11743
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        at com.example.admin.myapplication.MainActivity$HttpRequestTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:151)
        at com.example.admin.myapplication.MainActivity$HttpRequestTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:126)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:660)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:677)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)

Comment: What is value of `URL`? It may not be what you think it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception means exactly what it says: your OS has no network route to the destination. It can translate the hostname to an ip address, but when it tries to contact that destination there is no route.

Given that `localhost` is always routable my impression is that the service your code is trying to connect to is not `localhost` but some other service. If you would have included the full stacktrace it would have become apparent.

If you are trying to connect to a service running on your development machine from the Android running environment you need to [setup networking on the emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html).

Comment: I have given my systems ipaddress the same machine where I am running rest service then only it is giving this exception. if I give localhost it throws connection refused exception